# Should the methods of the interfaces throw exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, interface

I mean, in the definition. If I have a method of a class that implements an interface and I want to throw an exception, how can I do that if the interface don't have a throws declaration.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How is the code relying on your class implementing the interface going to know that it has to handle the new exception? You have two options:

1. Handle it in the interface method.
2. Throw an exception that inherits from [`RuntimeException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), which doesn't need to be in the `throws` clause. However, any code calling this method does not have to catch this exception nor does it know that it can be thrown. So be careful when using this option. Document them where possible, but you'll still face a problem when passing an object to an existing method such as a library or one that is built-in.

Comment: How is the code relying on your class implementing the interface going to know that it has to handle the new `RuntimeException`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip to all of you!

Comment: @marcog: So your point with "How is the code relying on your class implementing the interface going to know that it has to handle the new exception?" was?

Comment: @Martino No need to come across so aggressive. Made the answer a little clearer.

Comment: @marcog: Sorry if I came across a bit rude. This is a big nuissance in Java, and I'm tired of seeing people cheating the system and thinking everything will be alright. Glad you edited a warning into your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You simply don't or throw a RuntimeException.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot touch the interface, then your only choice is to throw a [`RuntimeException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). There are some standard RuntimeExceptions that you can use directly : `IllegalStateException`, `IllegalArgumentException`, `UsupportedOperationException`, etc.

Use these standard exceptions if they suit your needs, or create your own by extending the class `RuntimeException`. Consider documenting the thrown exceptions by using the `@throws` doclet in the javadoc.

Comment: And the corollary, of course: If you *are* in control of the interface, ensure that it declares appropriate checked exceptions (if any) and also use the `@throws` doclet to document any runtime exceptions implementations may be expected to throw. (No need to go overboard on that latter, but for instance an interface that accepts an index value should state clearly how implementations are expected to respond to an invalid index -- by returning some kind of flag value [like `null`], or by throwing an exception like `IllegalArgumentException`). The more thorough the interface docs, the better.

Answer (score 3):

The methods in your interface can declare to throw checked exceptions only if it makes sense for all the possible implementations to force the client to handle that exception.
Think of java.sql.Connection (an interface with all the methods throwing SQLException). Otherwise, if only one particular implementation has to deal with some checked exception, handle it there and either wrap it in some RuntimeException and rethrow or recover from that state if it makes sense.

Comment: I precisely want to throw SQLExceptions with all the implemented methods and NamingException for init() method.

Comment: Although I mentioned that example, I would advice against propagating the SQLException beyound your DAO layer (have a look at how Spring JDBC translates SQLExceptions into meaningful runtime exceptions extending from their DataAccessException).

Comment: Yes, I have it in mind. The interface is a middle component between the DAO layer and the database connection. Thanks.